# How to sync mail between PC and Mac

Tags: data-synchronization, windows, mail.app, email, ms-office

I have both a Mac and a PC. On the PC I use Outlook.

My question is, how do I sync mail between the PC and Mac? Previously I was keeping the .pst file from the PC on an external HD so I could see it on all my PCs, but now with a Mac, I'm at loss as to what to do. I still plan to use both Mac and PC.

Comment: Do you know what type of mail server you are using? How is your mail client set up currently? Do you know if you are using IMAP or POP?

Comment: Use IMAP.  You get builtin support that can sync Macs, PCs, tablets, smartphones, whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first instinct is to suggest using IMAP and just keeping all your mail etc on the server. Then it is as simple as using [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) or another Mac compatible mail client up to date with your email accounts.

However, I am assuming you have a reason to not go this route. An alternative would be to use [Outlook for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/outlook) if you're familiar with Outlook and wish to keep using it (and are okay with shelling out a little bit of money for it). I would like to believe that Microsoft kept compatibility with pst files alive in the transition.

Comment: Maybe he does not use IMAP because he does not know it. For me, IMAP is the only reasonable way to achieve his goal.

Comment: Also, Mail.app on the Mac supports IMAP. And I don't think the two outlooks can 'share' the PST.

Comment: @jmlumpkin To my knowledge, they can't share it. I assume the OP was separately importing the pst into each, which is rather painful. Hopefully IMAP is a possibility for the OP so he can avoid that fate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for backup & Restore of mails, you would love to use **[GMAIL back-up utility](http://www.gmail-backup.com/)**. I usually forward all mails from my account(a setting to send a copy to other account) to gmail account & I can always have backup on gmail. I can download all mails from GMAIL-Backup utility & similarly restore to specific account. This is what I did when I want to have backup of mails & transfer it to mac. You might not like the answer. But I explained what I did. So, this would be just a suggestion instead of an answer. ( once you have backup of all mails using gmail-Backup, you can copy in to pen-drive & then you can use it anywhere you want )